# Casting shared_ptr<Type> to weak_ptr<void> and back

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

How would I get a `weak_ptr<void>` to a `shared_ptr<Type>`?

How would I lock a `weak_ptr<void>` and ultimately produce a `shared_ptr<Type>`?

`Type` has a non-trivial destructor, is it right to assume `weak_ptr<...>` will never call this destructor?

The void weak pointer is what I want in this case, it's used only to keep tabs on the reference count of shared pointers of multiple types, and give out shared pointers to existing objects without itself owning the object (it's part of a one object many references resource manager).

Comment: Probably one of these casts: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking exactly about the destructor. Are you asking if destroying a `weak_ptr` can destroy the shared object? Or what exactly?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - Yes.  It shouldn't since it has no ownership over it, but I wanted to ask to be sure.  I can omit it if it makes the question muddy.

Comment: For example, if just you `foo.lock();` and `foo` is a `weak_ptr`, that can invoke the destructor under some conditions (because it creates and then destroys a `shared_ptr`).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But that is not the `weak_ptr` itself destroying the object, that is the resulting `shared_ptr` doing its job, destroying the object when all references to the object are gone. So there is no problem, because nobody is left to care.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Right, but it's easy to think that no operation on a `weak_ptr` can destroy the underlying object and that calling `lock` is an operation on the `weak_ptr`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How would I get a `weak_ptr<void>` to a `shared_ptr<Type>`?

`std::shared_ptr<Type>` is implicitly convertible to `std::weak_ptr<void>`.

> How would I lock a `weak_ptr<void>` and ultimately produce a `shared_ptr<Type>`?

Call `lock()` to get `std::shared_ptr<void>`, then use `std::static_pointer_cast`.

> `Type` has a non-trivial destructor, is it right to assume `weak_ptr<...>` will never call this destructor

Yes. Whenever the last `shared_ptr` is destroyed, the object is destroyed. If you want to keep the object alive, you should be storing `shared_ptr<void>` and not `weak_ptr<void>`. If you don't want to keep the object alive but you just want the `weak_ptr` to always know the reference count, then there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I thought I'd share this.  I needed to go one step further and cast a `weak_ptr<T>` to a `void*` to pass to a callback.

This casts a `shared_ptr<T>` to a `weak_ptr<void>` then to a `void*` and then back to `shared_ptr<T>`:

```
std::shared_ptr<T> sharedPtr = ....

std::weak_ptr<void> weakPtr = std::static_pointer_cast<void>(sharedPtr);
void* weakRef = static_cast<void*>(&weakPtr);
// Release shared pointer lock
sharedPtr.reset();

auto callback = [](void* &weakRef) -> bool {
  std::weak_ptr<void> weakPtr = *static_cast<Weak<void>*>(weakRef);
  auto sharedPtr = std::static_pointer_cast<T>(weakPtr.lock());

  if(sharedPtr){
    // ...
    return true;
  }
};
// Thread blocks here on callback, keeping weak_ptr count valid
wait(callback, weakRef);
```

Comment: That seems really convoluted. I‘m not even convinced that the shown code is valid. Anyways as you already use a lambda you could pass the the shared/weak per using lambda captures.

Comment: @t.niese the code is perfectly valid and runs as expected. The callback is passed as a typed function pointer so can't be passed as a capturing lambda and  std::function is not an option.